# Словообразование 999

Tags: словообразование

1) Обозначьте слова, к-ые образ. приставочным способом. Почему **размышление** и  **пристройка** образ. неприставочным способом, ведь если убрать приставки, то слова **мышление** и **стройка** существуют.
2) Слово **пятилетие** образовано сложением основ в сочетании с суффиксацией, то есть суффикс пятилет**ий**?
3) Почему **зелень** образовано нулевой суффиксацией. Объясните, пожалуйста, подробно.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это д/з.

Comment: уж много ты знаешь. я тут к ЦТ готовлюсь

Comment: Ну измени хотя бы подачу вопроса, а не сразу пункты без каких-то личных слов. И лишь в конце хотя бы просьба и даже "пожалуйста". Но относится-то она только к последнему пункту.

Comment: придирка. главное, чтобы смысл понятен был. И да, я люблю спорить.

Comment: Это не придирка, а просто правила хорошего тона формулировать вопрос по-человечески. Тут не дают заданий никому, как роботам. А спорить — было бы с чем.))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Почему размышление и пристройка образ. не приставочным способом, 
ведь если убрать приставки, то слова мышление и стройка существуют.
```

Слова-то существуют,но нельзя дать определение слову, на них основываясь:Размышление - это  результат действия размышлять. Пристройка- это результат действия пристроить.Нельзя сказать Размышление - это мышление, кот....Пристройка - это стройка чего-то...

2) пятилетие образовано сложением основ в сочетании с суффиксацией, корень пят+ интерфикс-и- + корень лет + суфф. -иj-

3) Слово зелень образовано нулевой суффиксацией. Зелень -растительность зелёного цвета. От прилаг.зелён/ый, но без суффикса(с нулевым содержанием суффикса),а вот зелён/к/а с суфф. -к-, зелен/щик с суфф.-щик